# auto authenticate password in mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, postgresql

I am new to MySql. In postgres, we can use .pgpass and save user password so that the database can automatically authenticate your password whenever you access or execute your sql script. I don't have to enter password.

So is there any way to do the same thing for mysql on linux?

Thanks

Comment: Does this help? http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/1001956

Comment: Tried it 10 times and have this error 'ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: NO)' but it works when i use following command 'mysql -u username -p database'. I have to enter password afterward.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can store default credentials and other options in your home directory, in a file called **$HOME/.my.cnf**

```
$ cat > $HOME/.my.cnf
[client]
user = scott
password = tiger
host = mydbserver
^D
```

In MySQL 5.6, you can also store an encrypted version of this file in **$HOME/.mylogin.cnf**, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-config-editor.html

```
$ mysql_config_editor set --user=scott --host=mydbserver --password
Enter password: ********
WARNING : 'client' path already exists and will be overwritten. 
 Continue? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : y

$ mysql_config_editor print --all
[client]
user = scott
password = *****
host = mydbserver
```

Comment: many thanks. your first method works just find. However, I prefer to the 2nd one. However, 'mysql_config_editor: command not found' after running the command. Not sure what's wrong. This is my mysql version 'mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.32, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2' by running 'mysql --version'.

Comment: mysql_config_editor is a new feature of MySQL 5.6.  I'll edit the above to make that more clear.

Comment: In MySQL 5.5, you can't get the encrypted .mylogin.cnf feature.  You should just be careful to limit the file permissions on $HOME/.my.cnf.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the command-line parameters available to the MySQL executable within a quick Bash script to accomplish this. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql.html for 
the details. Basically, the following line would log you into MySQL

```
$>mysql --user=root --password=toor my_database
```

The command above would log you into the mysql database "my_database" as root using the password "toor"

Now but this into a quick Bash script (run_mysql.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/mysql --user=root --password=toor my_database
```

Make sure the script is executable:

```
chmod +x ./run_mysql.sh
```

Of course make sure this script is safely stored somewhere other users cannot access it such as your home folder and set the permissions accordingly.

Comment: Thanks but this is not for universal technique. I would have to change my database name if I want to work with other database. Thanks though.